# My ethereum balance returns 0 when checked via geth, but according to etherchain it has a value

Tags: ethernet, ethereum

I have the exact same problem as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36210228/my-ethereum-balance-seems-to-be-0-when-checked-via-geth/45595628#45595628) but the solution doesn't help (so don't flag this post).

Instead of the other post, I think my connectivity works fine. At least I get a number higher than 0 when I enter `net.peerCount`.

Furthermore I waited 24h+ connected to the ether network.

What am I missing? What am I doing wrong?

When I type `geth attach` it tells me that the parameter at block: 0 (Thu, 01 Jan 1970 01:00:00 CET)... maybe this is the problem? My OS time is correct.

Answer (score 2):

If `eth.blockNumber` returns 0 then you are not synced to blockchain. The block number should match https://ethstats.net/ which is approximately 4,100,000 right now

So you are not synced with the network.

Things to check:

- Are you running the latest client?
- Are you connecting to the right network and *not* testnet?
- Are you on a network which blocks peer-to-peer traffic? Ethereum traffic looks a lot like bittorrent traffic and a lot of workplaces block it
- What do your peers (`admin.peers`) look like? Do *they* have the latest clients? What are *their* block numbers?

You can try running geth in higher verbosity

```
LOGGING AND DEBUGGING OPTIONS:
  --verbosity value         Logging verbosity: 0=silent, 1=error, 2=warn, 3=info, 4=core, 5=debug, 6=detail (default: 3)
```

Hope this helps! If all fails you can use a public ethereum node like Infura - https://infura.io/#how-to

Comment: instead of `eth.peers`, should it be `admin.peers` ?